# A regular expression to set automatic links

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex, ruby-on-rails-3

I have an article model:

```
class Article < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :content
end
```

I now want to add a before_save :createlinks callback that automatically subsitutes all words inside the article with links in case the word is also the name of another article. E.g. I have an article called "Test" and I create a new article with the :content "You can see a test here." I need an automatic link to the "Test" article between ther words "a" and "here".

My approach is to add in article.rb:

```
before_save :createlinks

def createlinks
  Article.all.each do |article|
    unless self.name == article.name
      self.content.gsub!(/#{article.name}/i, "<%= link_to '#{article.name}', 'http://localhost:3000/articles/#{article.id}' %>")
    end
  end
end
```

The first unless line just to avoid articles linking to itself. This works fine for the first update action, but the seconds update subsitutes all "link_to 'Test'. etc..." with "link_to 'link_to' etc".

So I want to exclude that gsub substitutes all names that are between two '-characters (which means it's already substituted with a link_to 'Test'). My approach is:

unless self.content =~ /'#{article.name}'/ || self.name == article.name

This works too, in principle, but this leads to a result that as soon as one link is created no other links will be set anymore because as soon as one 'Test' is found the whole gsub is skipped.

What is the best way to solve this? Is there a regex for "substitute all where self.content is article.name but only if article.name is without a ' before the word"? In other words how do I add a character in a regex that should NOT be there? Or is there a better way to resolve the whole issue?

Answer (score 0):

```
def extract_name(title)
  match = title.match /'(.*)'/
  match ? match[1] : title
end

def createlinks
  Article.all.each do |article|
    extracted_title = extract_name(article.name)
    unless self.name == extracted_title
      self.content.gsub!(/#{article.name}/i, link_to(extracted_title, 'http...'), 'http://localhost:3000/articles/#{article.id}' %>")
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I couldn't get it working... what is the 'http...' in there? And in articles#show I had a simple_format(@article.content) that doesn't work with your proposal.

Comment: I just provided the template, it's not tested, it's just there to give you ideas on how to solve the problem.  the 'http...' represents the link you want insert

Comment: Ok, now I have it. But I still have the same problem: the unless self.name == extracted_title leads to the problem that it just substitutes the link the first time, after that it doen't subsitute the other article.name anymore since it ignores the gsub line...